# react-native-iap listen to Apple new purchase and cannot verify the transaction

Tags: app-store, verify, in-app-purchase-receipt

In our Front End we use react-native-iap to listen for the App Store purchase.

We get a purchase that have encoded receipt and transaction ID. Then we call Apple API `verifyReceipt` . From the data we get back we try to compare the transaction ID we get before to the list of transactions we get from Apple API. However, sometimes we cannot find the transaction ID in the response from `verifyReceipt`. That has caused our app to throw a lot of errors and we cannot finish the purchase.

Has anyone encountered such problem and do you know why it happen?